# How to realize custom field class on Ext.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext.net

I need to create field for date and time. Now it looks something like this

```
    @X.Container().Items(X.Panel().Layout(LayoutType.HBox).Items(
        X.Label(field.Name), 
        X.Panel().Layout(LayoutType.HBox).Width(200).Items(
             X.DateFieldFor(valueExpression).FieldLabel(null), 
             X.TimeFieldFor(valueExpression).FieldLabel(null))
```

It doesn't work correctly. I want to create my own class inherited from, for example, Field. And it must work like one ordinary standard control.

What methods I must override from base field classes or/and builder base classes most of all? And how to build own control with standard?